# Compiling .c files and .s files from different different subdirectories

Tags: makefile, linker-errors, gnu-make

Here is my makefile http://pastie.org/1104332. I am trying to compile different .c files and .s files (assembly files) from different sub directories into E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680/ then the linker should link all the .o files from the build directory (E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680) into a file named mfg-sample-app.out.
When I run the makefile which I posted above then the compiler compiles all the source files into object files in the build directory but the linker can not open the object files because its not looking for them in the build directory which is E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680. I dont know how why the linker does not look there? that is the error I get:

```
E:\IARSystems\EmbeddedWorkbench5.4Evaluation\arm\bin\ilinkarm.exe"      -o E:/e
m35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680/mfg-sample-app.out --
map E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680/mfg-sample-ap
p.map --log initialization,modules,sections,veneers --log_file E:/em35x/build/mf
g-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680/mfg-sample-app.log --config E:/em3
5x/app/mfglib/ewb-em357/../../../hal/micro/cortexm3/em35x/em357/iar-cfg.icf --di
ag_suppress Lp012 --entry halEntryPoint  E:/em35x/build/alarm-library-cortexm3-i
ar-em357-em3xx/alarm-library.a E:/em35x/build/binding-table-stub-library-cortexm
3-iar-em357-em3xx/binding-table-stub-library.a  E:/em35x/build/cbke-stub-library
-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx/cbke-stub-library.a E:/em35x/build/end-device-bind-stu
b-library-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx/end-device-bind-stub-library.a  E:/em35x/buil
d/hal-library-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx/hal-library.a E:/em35x/build/mfglib-libra
ry-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx/mfglib-library.a  E:/em35x/build/security-library-co
re-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx/security-library-core.a E:/em35x/build/security-libr
ary-link-keys-stub-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx/security-library-link-keys-stub.a E:
/em35x/build/zigbee-pro-stack-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx/zigbee-pro-stack.a E:/em3
5x/app/mfglib/mfg-sample.o E:/em35x/hal/ember-configuration.o E:/em35x/hal/micro
/cortexm3/adc.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/bootloader-interface-app.o E:/em35x/
hal/micro/cortexm3/bootloader-interface-standalone.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3
/bootloader-interface.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/button.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/
cortexm3/buzzer.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/cstartup-iar-common.o E:/em35x/hal
/micro/cortexm3/diagnostic.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/led.o E:/em35x/hal/micr
o/cortexm3/mfg-token.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/micro-common.o E:/em35x/hal/m
icro/cortexm3/micro.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/sleep.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cor
texm3/token-def.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/token.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm
3/uart.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/generic/crc.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/generic/endian.o E:
/em35x/hal/micro/generic/mem-util.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/generic/random.o E:/em35x
/hal/micro/generic/sim-eeprom.o E:/em35x/app/util/serial/cli.o E:/em35x/app/util
/serial/serial.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/em35x/mpu.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cort
exm3/faults.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/isr-stubs.o

   IAR ELF Linker V5.50.5.51995/W32 for ARM
   Copyright (C) 2007-2010 IAR Systems AB.
Fatal error[Li001]: could not open file "E:\em35x\app\mfglib\mfg-sample.o"
Fatal error detected, aborting.
make: *** [mfg-sample-app.out] Error 3
```

(first it compiles the source files but at the end it cannot find the object files in the build folder)

Now after I delete line 70 from the makefile which is

```
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o) E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/faults.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/isr-stubs.o
```

then the linker can find the previous compiled object files in the build directory and creates the .out file. And if I manually delete all the object files from the build directory (which the compiler created previously) and run the makefile again (line 70 is still deleted) then I get this error:

```
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em3
57-em3xx-dev0680/mfg-sample.o', needed by `mfg-sample-app.out'.  Stop.
```

And if I add line 70 again which is :

```
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o) E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/faults.o E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/isr-stubs.o
```

then it compiles again but does not link because it cannot open the object files. (The first mentioned error again)

I dont know what I am doing wrong. I have tried many things but cannot find my problem.

Thanks

**EDIT**: I am using GNU Make 3.81

have changed the second-to-last line to:

```
$(END_DIR)/%.o : %.c
```

and I also made changes to VPATH as suggested by Gilles but no luck.

Now I get this erorr:

```
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em3
57-em3xx-dev0680/mfg-sample.o', needed by `mfg-sample-app.out'.  Stop.
```

It is not compiling any .c file into a .o file

**EDIT:** Beta, I will be able to test you lines on Monday. I will then report the results, I want to resolve this issue it is driving me crazy. Thanks

**EDIT:**

Hi Beta,

I am still getting the same error with the code you suggested. This is the error, if mfg-sample.o is not in the build folder (E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em3
        57-em3xx-dev0680) :

```
tjoyia@TJ-PC /e/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680
$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em3
57-em3xx-dev0680/mfg-sample.o', needed by `mfg-sample-app.out'.  Stop.
```

But if mfg-sample.o already exists in the build folder (after I complied mfg-sample.c to mfg-sample.o) then I get this message:

```
tjoyia@TJ-PC /e/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680
$ make
found E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680/mfg-sample.
o, making mfg-sample-app.out
```

**EDIT:**

Hi Beta,
Yes, that worked.

I got this message:

```
tjoyia@TJ-PC /e/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680
$ make
found E:/em35x/app/mfglib/mfg-sample.c, making E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cor
texm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680/mfg-sample.o
found E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680/mfg-sample.
o, making mfg-sample-app.out
```

So, what should I do now in my original makefile? I want to compile my whole project and link the object files.(all my .c files in different path locations into the build folder and then the linker should link the previous created .o files into the .out file)

**EDIT:**

Hi Beta,

Ok I got it working, but what about the two .s79 files how I can get them also compiled into object files in the build directory? Why is VPATH not working and I think my dependcy file creation (.d) is not invoked how I can get the invoked. I want all the .h files (#include statements in the source files) get automatically recognized and depend on the object file.

And after that I want to convert the .out files but its not getting invoked.

Here is the problem:

Do you know how I could add this to my makefile:

ielftool.exe --srec --verbose E:\em35x\build\mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680\mfg-sample-app.out E:\em35x\build\mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680\mfg-sample-app.s37

It should convert the mfg-sample-app.out file into a mfg-sample-app.s37 after the .out file is created/linked from the object files.

Answer (score 1):

First, that link doesn't point to a makefile, it points to the output of your attempt to run make. Second, I don't see evidence there that it actually produced  `mfg-sample-app.o`, but you say it did so I'll take your word for it.

There are a couple of different things that could be causing this error. I suggest you restore line 70, start from a clean slate and run make *twice*. I think there's a good chance it'll build the object files on the first pass and find them on the second. And no matter what it does, we'll learn something. (I'd suggest you also change to a more reputable compiler/linker, like gcc, but it looks as if this one uses some flags in a non-standard way.)

The second error you got is easy to understand: you deleted the line that defined a list of objects, and a rule was defined in terms of that list, so Make didn't know how to build those objects any more. But it scares me that Make knew how to invoke the linker without that list; it suggests that your makefile has a lot of redundancy in it, which is bad.

By the way, **what make are you using?** Try running `make -v` and see what it says.

**EDIT:**
Now that I can look at the makefile, I think I can clear up this mystery.

The source file in question is `E:/em35x/app/mfglib/mfg-sample.c`. With line 70 in place, Make just changes `.c` to `.o` and concludes that the object file in question is `E:/em35x/app/mfglib/mfg-sample.o`. But you've hard-coded the build directory path into the compiler flags (a *very* bad practice), so that's where the objects files go. Then when Make gets to the linking step it can't find `E:/em35x/app/mfglib/mfg-sample.o`, and dies.

When you run without line 70, it uses the earlier line and concludes that `mfg-sample.o` should be in the build directory. If that object file is already there before you run, Make links the object files together and all is well. But if the file is not there, then Make cannot build it, because this makefile knows only one way to build an object file and that is by compiling source code *that is in the same directory where it intends to build the object*. Since there is no such source file in the build directory, it dies.

This makefile could use a lot of work, but here's the smallest change that will (probably) solve your problem. (You haven't said what version of Make you use-- this works for GNUMake.) Get rid of line 70 and modify the second-to-last line:

```
$(END_DIR)/%.o : %.c
```

Now, no matter where Make thinks the object file should go, it will look for the source file without the path (`mfg-sample.c`) and VPATH will find it.

**P.S.** Gilles has pointed out that the delimiter in VPATH may not work in Windows. If the change I suggest doesn't work, try also changing the delimiter as Gilles suggests (changing the delimiter alone won't help).

**EDIT:**
VPATH doesn't seem to be working. We can do without it, but I'd like to try one last experiment before we abandon it. Please try this and tell us what happens:

```
END_DIR = E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680

OBJ = $(END_DIR)/mfg-sample.o 

VPATH = E:/em35x/app/mfglib

mfg-sample-app.out : $(OBJ)
  @echo found $<, making $@

$(END_DIR)/%.o : %.c
  @echo found $<, making $@
  @touch $@
```

**EDIT 3:**
All right, VPATH isn't working-- maybe later we can figure out why.

Try this (it might work, it might not-- it's hard for me to test the Windows-style paths):

```
END_DIR = E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680

OBJ = $(END_DIR)/mfg-sample.o 

mfg-sample-app.out : $(OBJ)
  @echo found $<, making $@

$(END_DIR)/mfg-sample.o : E:/em35x/app/mfglib/mfg-sample.c

$(END_DIR)/%.o :
  @echo found $<, making $@
  @touch $@
```

**EDIT 4:**

Cross your fingers and try splicing this into your real makefile (and get rid of line 70):

```
$(END_DIR)/mfg-sample.o: E:/em35x/app/mfglib/mfg-sample.c

$(END_DIR)/ember-configuration.o: E:/em35x/hal/ember-configuration.c

CORTEXM3 = adc \
bootloader-interface-app \
bootloader-interface-standalone \
bootloader-interface \
button \
buzzer \
cstartup-iar-common \
diagnostic \
led \
mfg-token \
micro-common \
micro \
sleep \
token-def \
token \
uart

CORTEXM3_OBJS = $(patsubst %,$(END_DIR)/%.o,$(CORTEXM3))
$(CORTEXM3_OBJS): $(END_DIR)/%.o : E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/%.c

GENERIC = crc \
endian \
mem-util \
random \
sim-eeprom

GENERIC_OBJS = $(patsubst %,$(END_DIR)/%.o,$(GENERIC))
$(GENERIC_OBJS): $(END_DIR)/%.o : E:/em35x/hal/micro/generic/%.c

$(END_DIR)/cli.o $(END_DIR)/serial.o: $(END_DIR)/%.o : E:/em35x/app/util/serial/%.c

$(END_DIR)/mpu.o: E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/em35x/mpu.c

$(END_DIR)/%.o :
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $<
```

See why VPATH is so handy?

**EDIT 5:**

**The s79 files:**

We change the rule (the last two lines of EDIT 4):

```
# change this:
#
# $(END_DIR)/%.o :
#    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $<

# to this:

$(END_DIR)/mfg-sample.o \
$(END_DIR)/ember-configuration.o \
$(CORTEXM3_OBJS) \
$(GENERIC_OBJS) \
$(END_DIR)/cli.o $(END_DIR)/serial.o \
$(END_DIR)/mpu.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $<
```

(You can put those targets on one line if you like, I was going for readability.)

Verify that this works, then put in another rule for the s79 sources:

```
$(END_DIR)/faults.o $(END_DIR)/isr-stubs.o : $(END_DIR)/%.o : E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/%.s79
    @echo attempting to build $@ from $<
    $(ASM) $(AFLAG) $(AFLAG1) $(AFLAG2) $(AFLAG3) $(AFLAG4) $<
```

And be sure to append those two to the `OBJ` variable, so that Make will know what `mfg-sample-app.out` needs.

**VPATH.** I don't know why VPATH isn't working. More investigation is possible, but it's very difficult to do remotely like this. You can try a long shot: in the experimental makefile I suggested (in the second EDIT block) change the VPATH line to this:

```
vpath %.c E:/em35x/app/mfglib
```

(Note the lower case.)

**Dependency files (.d).** I don't know whether the commands in the rules work (I don't have access to your "Embedded Workbench" tools), but the reason the rules aren't being invoked is that the `include` statements use a variable (`sources`) which is undefined. Make can't find any source files that way, so it doesn't think it has to include anything, so it doesn't think it has to build anything (and couldn't even if it wanted to because it can't find the sources). You can use the `SRC` variable instead, but don't forget to add in the s79 files.

**Converting the .out files.** Piece of cake:

```
E:\em35x\build\mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680\mfg-sample-app.s37 : mfg-sample-app.out
    ielftool.exe --srec --verbose $< $@
```

(If you want this to be your default target, put it before all others.) I hard-coded the path to the s37 target because you specified it. You could probably do with just `mfg-sample-app.s37`.

Comment: have changed the link. Now it points to the makefile. Please look into it

Comment: I must use this compiler for the projects in the special flag options.

Comment: It only builds the the objects when line 70 is not ommited and overrides the previous OBJ variable in the makefile. When I ommit line 70 and use the OBJ variable before line 70 then it links the objects (if they are already built in the build directory) if I delete them then it gives the error which I mentioned in the second part of my question

Comment: will be able to test it on Monday.Thanks

Comment: and what about the .s79 files?

Answer (score 0):

You have two definitions of OBJ. One explicitly lists all of the objects and says they are in the END_DIR, but there's no rule to build an object file in one place from a source file in a different directory. The second rule uses the source files and replaces .c with .o (and the object files would be in the same directory as the source).

After you deleted the second rule, make used the first definition to identify where the object files should be for linking, but didn't know how to generate them. This explains the second error. To fix it, either modify the compilation rule to place the object files in a different directory, or use use the rule on line 70 that says they are in the same place as the source.

It's not clear why the first pass didn't work, but I'd recommend taking out the generation and inclusion of the dependence files (`.d`) until the compilation is working. I've found that it's far more useful to build them as a side effect of compilation than to create them explicitly. If they don't exist, then you haven't compiled anything and have to do a complete build anyway.

Comment: I dont know what you mean exactly? What should I do? What I want is to compile the source files (which are in different subdirectories) in the build folder (object files). Then the linker should link all the object files from the build folder into a .out file.

Comment: taking out the generation and inclusion of the dependence files (.d) did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

The linker is doing exactly what it's told: it's told to link "E:\em35x\app\mfglib\mfg-sample.o", which doesn't exist.

There is a problem in the definition of `VPATH` in the makefile: `:` is used both as the DOS/Windows drive indicator and as the path separator. On Windows, you must replace `:` by `;` or by blanks. (This might break compatibility with other unix implementations of make, which is probably why the author of the script that generated this (part of the) makefile used `:`.)

```
VPATH = E:/em35x/app/mfglib/ E:/em35x/hal/ E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/ E:/em35x/hal/micro/generic/ E:/em35x/app/util/serial/ E:/em35x/hal/micro/cortexm3/ E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680/
```

Comment: but mfg-sample.o is in E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680/

How can I tell the linker to link E:/em35x/build/mfg-sample-app-cortexm3-iar-em357-em3xx-dev0680/mfg-sample.o

Comment: @ATJ: That's what the person who wrote the makefile intended to happen, with the `VPATH` feature. `VPATH` tells `make` to look for dependencies in the indicated directories in addition to the current directory (look it up in the `make` manual for more information). Try the change I suggest, it should work provided there isn't another bug in the makefile.